# Maven/SpringData/Neo4J: add Gremlin 1.4

Tags: java, maven, gremlin, spring-data-neo4j

I wanna use Gremlin in my SpringData repositories the same way I use Cypher. AFAIK, only Gremlin 1.4 is supported with Neo4J 1.6 and SpringData/Neo4J 2.0.0.

Is this correct ?

Anyhow, I cannot find gremlin-groovy 1.4 in Maven Central ? Is there another way I can add it as a dependency ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/public](http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/public/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/gremlin-groovy/1.4/)